# GitBash keeps prompting me for username and password for GitHub

Tags: github, git-bash

I've been using gitbash for a while to work with github but every time when I push or pull I have to type my github username and password in a new prompt.

I've tried to clone github rep using ssh:// instead of https:// but when I type like that:

git clone ssh://github.com/user/repo.git I get the following:

```
$ git clone ssh://github.com/user/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.112)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.112' (RSA) to the list of      known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to clone using HTTPS instead of ssh.

SSH link would something like this

**git@github.com:domain/repositoryName.git**

you can look for the ssh link by clicking on clone or download tab there you will find option to use ssh.

Comment: Thanks I didn't see it before. I had to add my ssh key on github and that's it. It works now!